# How many binary sequences of length n satisfy constraints

Tags: combinatorics

Let Sn be a sequence of ones and zeros, of length n
Let C(a,b,c) be the constraint defined as:

Subsequence starting from the a-ith element of the sequence, ending at b (included), must have value c, when XOR is applied.

1001 -> 0

Intersections of Cs may or may not be empty sets.

How might one go about counting how many Sn satisfy a set of constraints?

My thinking so far:

-XOR upon a sequence returns 1 when an odd number of elements are 1

-Define sets that satisfy each constraint, their size is 
Sum over all odd x (b-a+1)chooseX, X<=(b-a+1),

To this we add 2^(n-b+a-1)

But, their intersections are non empty. I am not sure how to apply the principle of inclusion to such a problem. Perhaps a different approach is a better choice?

Comment: What is the probability that the XOR value is c, for $c \in \{0,1\}$?

Comment: No probability is given. Perhaps I'm missing something. We are counting all sequences.

Comment: I don't think there exist a simple relation computing what you want. Perhaps a reccurence, splitting intersections into two disjoint parts and summing. But even that won't account for possibilities where half ways down you encounter a contradiction.